# What is the usefulness of matrix decomposition?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Both $LU$, $LDL^T$ and Cholesky decomposition require to use $O(n^3)$ to solve it. However, the time complexity is the same as Gaussian Elimination Method. Some Lecturers say that it can increase the speed of solving $Ax=b$. In fact, these decompositions can only reduce some constant factors for this problem. Therefore, what is the usage of these decompositions?

Answer (score 2):

The factorizations are particularly useful if you have to solve $Ax=b$ for many right hand sides.  Each solution takes $O(n^{2})$ time once the factorization has been computed.

Comment: For many "right hand sides" case:
If we calculate $A^{-1}$ first, then we use it many times. We can still get $O(n^2)$ time. After we obtain $A^{-1}$, It is simply doing the matrix-vector multiplication (matrix $A^{-1}$ and vector $b$).

Comment: Therefore, does it mean that we can simply use Gaussian Elimination method to obtain $A^{-1}$, and solve this problem for many $b$ in $O(n^2)$ time in later stage?

Comment: You don't need to actually compute $A^{-1}$, just factor $A$ as $A = LU$ (for example) and then $LU x = b$ can be solved efficiently (in $O(n^2)$ time) by solving $Ly = b$ and then $Ux = y$ using back substitution.

Comment: When I first learned numerical analysis, I thought, "Yeah, but when are we ever gonna need to solve $Ax = b$ for many different right hand sides?"  Later I realized, this actually happens all the time in iterative algorithms, such as many algorithms in convex optimization.

Comment: I know that we can use forward and backward substitution to solve this problem in $O(n^2)$ time. I mean we can first obtain $A^{-1}$ and store it, then use the matrix-vector multiplication to solve $x=A^{-1}b$. The time complexity is still $O(n^2)$. Therefore, in terms of theoretical time complexity, what is the difference between using the LU decomposition and Gaussian Elimination?

Comment: @user295106 Inverting matrices is a numerical no-no.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, that we want to solve $Ax = b$ for a single RHS and $n\times n$ dense matrix A. Algorithmic complexity of the LU method and the Gausian elimination method is the same and equal $2/3n^3+O(n^2)$.

This would suggest, that the Gausian elimination can be efficient at least for some problems. However this is far from true. The algorithmic complexity does not take into account memory issues. The LU factorization can be easily optimized for memory accesses using different blocking techiques. Such optimized version are over 10 times faster, than unoptimized version for a moderately large matrices ($n$ of order $10^3$) and even faster for larger ones.

The Gausian elimination is not "memory friendly". Probably it could be also blocked, but resulting algorithm would be (probably) close to the LU factorization.

Comment: It means that the time is smaller for the practical situation when we use the LU factorization. However, it is difficult for us to reduce the theoretical time complexity.

Comment: @user295106 When time complexity is calculated, then always we have a concrete implementantion in mind. The number of floating point operations for both algoritms using standard implementations is the same. Blocked variants of the LU factorization can be implemented using "fast multiplications", which reduces its complexity. The time complexity should take into account the most expensive operations. When computations are performed in a single or double precision, then the most expensive operation is random access to memory. Thus, considering only numer of flops can lead to wrong conclusions.